# Mixture design experiment and regression

Tags: regression, logistic, experiment-design

I have an experiment with four groups with multiple trials. In two groups individuals have the exact same trials during all the experiment, no variation   In the stimuli were added. But in the other two groups the trials have a little difference (level of the stimuli varied).

Now I’m doing a logistic regression to analyze this data. This mixture design (between/within subjects) have implications to the way I design my LR model? How can I make the model take this difference into consideration? Please, If you have some textual reference on this I would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you share your data?  Or even just a visualization of the data?

Comment: What is the formula of your LR model? What is your goal? What do you mean by "make the model take this difference into consideration"? Or do you just want to know whether or not you have to take care of this difference?

Comment: The four groups have the same data structure. The response variable has 30 trials that are binary so responses can be 0 or 1 in . 

The structure is the same for all groups. 

The main difference is that for groups 1 and 2 participants were presented for the same exact stimuli in all the 30 trials. But in groups 3 and 4 the the stimuli vary in  levels of the presented stimuli. So in groups 3 and 4 I have 10 trials for each level of the stimuli.

Comment: In the main analysis I didn't take this difference into consideration. I just made an analysis considering only the for main groups. But right now I would like to take this difference into a secondary analysis.

Comment: In this sense, I created a response variable that has 8 levels 
(Group 1 = level 1; Group 2 = level 2; Group 3 = level 3, 4, and 5;  
and Group 4 = levels 6, 7, 8.) .
The model is the response (0, 1) ~Treatment (1-8 variable). So the question is how much the different treatments impacts the response variable.  
What I need to know is if I need the model to take into account that the, for exemple, the levels 3, 4, and 5 all come from the same group/participants. So in this sense. I "just want to know whether or not you have to take care of this difference".

Comment: Please add all this extra information to the Q as an edit. On this site comments are often seen by very few ... and can be deleted!